# Выборка и сортировка

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных есть несколько таблиц:

- `katalog` - каталог продукции
- `group` - группы к которым принадлежит товар
- `color` - тут представлены всевозможные цвета с их id
- `colors_t` - тут присваиваются цвета товарам, т.е. id товара->id цвета из таблицы colosr

Необходимо сделать запрос на выборку всех единиц товара из таблицы `katalog` с их параметрами, группой и цветами и экспортировать в Excel. Сам запрос я составил используя JOIN, все что нужно вытащилось все хорошо, но есть один момент, у одного товара может быть несколько цветов и по этой причине сформированная таблица получается вида:

- Название-группа-цвет
- Этот же товар название-группа-другой цвет

Как сделать объединение или сортировку чтобы было: название-группа-все цвета данного товара.

Answer (score 1):

а может сделать 2 запроса
1) все о товаре кроме цвета
2) все цвета товара (зациклить)

потом объединить полученное ?

Comment: Можно и так, были такие мысли, решил на всякий случай проконсультироваться, вдруг еще предложения какие будут)

Comment: ну а зачем изобретать велосипед? Накручивать сложный SQL запрос.